# About $ \lim_{n \to \infty}na_{n} $

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Consider a non-monotonic sequence $ \left \{ a_{n} \right \}$, $a_{n} \geq 0$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

If, the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}$ converges
then is it necessary to have $\lim_{n \to \infty}na_{n} = 0$?

I am able to prove that $ \liminf na_{n} = 0 $ using Pringsheim's theorem, but how can I confirm or counter the convergence of $ \left \{ na_{n} \right \}$?

Comment: No, just let $a_{2^k} = 2^{-k}$ and $a_n = 0$ otherwise

Answer (score 5):

Consider the sequence
$$
a_n=\cases{\frac1n& if $n$ is a power of 2\\0& otherwise}
$$
Its sum is $2$. Yet $na_n$ is equal to $1$ whenever $n$ is a power of $2$, and $0$ otherwise, so $na_n$ doesn't converge.

Answer (score 3):

Take $a_n=\frac 1 n $ when $n=m^{2}$ for some $m$ and $0$ otherwise.